# Design select style in HTML?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

What is [this](http://www.uphinhnhanh.com/images/7717301_homepage_tn.jpg)? Button or Select ? How do like this by HTML and CSS ? Thank

[image]

Comment: It is an image of `<select>`

Comment: I think this should be a button.

Comment: It a select in a shape of button.

Comment: Right-click in Chrome and use 'Inspect Element'. You can then see the html and css.

Comment: +AlieN, +null you are have fun :))
more specific:
http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/4080/nxrg.jpg

Comment: @ScottSimpson: I cut from PSD image file . I can not demo

Comment: @user2935043, if you cut it from a PSD then it's a slice from a PSD. It is not a button or a select (or anything else) until you make it one of those things.

Answer (score 4):

This is most probably a styled select element. Take a look at this tutorial http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/

Answer (score 0):

This can be a simple div with 3 elements in it.

1) The image - with the top and the bottom arrow.

2) The ul tag - when clicked on the image, the ul's get displayed.

3) The label - when any of the li's is selected, its value is copied to the label

Answer (score 0):

you can do thing like this with simple div. something like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/e5FsX/)

```
<div id="button"><span>Location</span></div>

#button
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius:15px;
    position:relative;
}
#button>span
{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a plugin that lets you do this here is a link; just download the files include the script and css run

```
$('document').ready(function(){         
    $('select').niceselect();
})
```

and you can then style it however you want using css.

http://projects.authenticstyle.co.uk/niceselect/

Answer (score 0):

This is a **Select** element.

Check this Example : [dropdown list](http://codepen.io/Thibaut/pen/Jasci)

Answer (score 0):

advice how to solve that kind of problems

IF you are using Chrome,Firefox... you can **right click** on any element on page then **inspect element**

and see HTML  CSS  even  JS for that element

Read more about Chrome Developer tools
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/